# Is this a convolution?

Tags: integration, convolution

I have the following integral
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) q(t+ax) dt
\end{align*}

where a is some constant.

This integral look a lot like convolution (or correlation). My question is can it be re-write as an convolution of $ f(???)* g(???)$? What are the arguments of the two functions? For example if the integral was $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) q(at+ax) dt$ then we can re-write as
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) q(at+ax) dt= f(x)*q(ax)
\end{align*}

**This is what I tried**
I did some integral manipulation and I got this identity 
\begin{align*}
\int f(t) q(t+ax) dt=\int f(t-ax) q(t) dt
\end{align*}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A convolution integral is of the form

$$\int f(t) g(x-t) \, dt;$$

the important point is the structure of the arguments:

$$x-t \qquad \text{and} \qquad t$$

In order to write the given integral as a convolution integral, we define $\tilde{q}(t) := q(-t)$. Then

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) q(t+ax) \, dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) \tilde{q}(-ax-t) \, dt = (f \ast \tilde{q})(-ax).$$

Comment: So is this a convolution of $f(x)$ with $\bar{q}(-ax)=q(ax)$???

Comment: @Boby Note that $(f*\tilde{q})(-ax) \neq (f*q)(ax)$. The first expression means: Calculate the convolution of $f$ with $\tilde{q}$ and *then* evaluate this function at $-ax$.

Comment: You see I want apply fourier transform and use the fact that convolution is a product. I have to know what the time domain functions

Comment: @Boby So you have to calculate the Fourier transform of $\tilde{q}$. Where are you stuck?

Comment: I just don't know how to proceed with your notation. In Fourie domain $(f*q)(x)$ is $G(\omega)*Q(\omega)$ is Fourier transform of $(f*q)(ax)$ give by $\frac{1}{a} F(\frac{\omega}{a}) Q(\frac{\omega}{a}$??

Comment: @Boby No, it is not. First you have to figure out the Fourier transform of $\tilde{q}$. Just use the definition of Fourier transform!

Comment: @Boby It is gonna be $\frac{1}{|a|}F(\frac{\omega}{-a})\tilde{Q}(\frac{\omega}{-a})$